# Qt QLCDNumber QTimer Digital Clock Tick

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I am trying to create a digital clock. However, my purpose is not getting the currentTime(). Instead, I am defining my own time and incrementing the time from there onwards.

However, in my codes, I am able to call tickSimulation(), but the clock timer won't start ticking. It just stucks at 11:00:00. Is declaring addSecs(1000) correct?

Please help. Thanks!

```
StatusBar::StatusBar()
{
    createButtons();
    time = new QTime(11, 0, 0);
};

void StatusBar::createButtons()
{
    ...
    lcdSimulation = new QLCDNumber;
    lcdSimulation->setNumDigits(8);
    simulationTimer = new QTimer;
    simulationTimer->start(1000);
    QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tickSimulation()));
    addWidget(lcdSimulation);
    ...
}

void StatusBar::tickSimulation()
{
    QString text = time->toString(Qt::TextDate);
    if((time->second() % 2) == 0)
        text[2] = ' ';
    lcdSimulation->display(text);
    time->addSecs(1000);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTime's addSecs function is returning new QTime object when you call it. So you need to use returned object to show correct time

```
QTime n(11, 0, 0);
QTime t;
t = n.addSecs(1000); 
//use t to show correct time
```

See [QTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtime.html#addSecs) doc here for more information.